# В каком приложении писать код для сайта?

Tags: веб-программирование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что лучше использовать? До этого сколько читал, многие склонялись и указывал использовать софт SimpleText. Сейчас вот узнал, что есть такая вещь Microsoft WebMatrix, с вида выглядит очень прилично, но информации в Интернете в плане отзывов по ней почти нет. Ещё пару раз встречал, что упоминают продукт от Adobe, adobe dreamweaver. Что можете о ней сказать? И чем всё таки в принципе лучше пользоваться при написание сайта?

Comment: Многое зависит от того, на чем вы собираетесь писать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начни с Notepad++.
Если хочешь именно IDE, то попробуй Eclipse или NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/).

Если под Mac — другой отличный вариант [Coda](http://panic.com/coda/).

Answer (score 0):

[Geany](http://www.geany.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на [Atom](https://atom.io/) editor, похож на notepad++, легкий и бесплатный!